# Sphinx search setup on load balanced app servers

Tags: amazon-ec2, sphinx, load-balancing, autoscaling

I would like to use sphinxsearch on our site which is hosted on an auto-scaled load-ballanced server farm with 1LB, 2DB, 2APP,& 1 memcached servers. 
With using sphinx to search a site with over million posts (forum site), is any of these ideas a recommended way to setup sphinxsearch.

a: Setup a extra server (or put it on the memcache instance) and have results from the app servers pull from that server.

b: setup sphinxsearch on the app servers and find a way to replicated the index

c: what ever other idea you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

A) Try putting it on separate server first, if it will not take a lot of resources you can move it to memcache server.

B) Replicating indexes would actually be rsyncing them? If yes you would need to restart search daemon after every sync so I would not suggest it

I would go with A

Comment: re B) - no, you dont need to restart sphinx on the replicas, can just 'reload' - so there is no interuption in searching. Exactly like indexer does when use --rotate to update an index. http://www.ivinco.com/blog/sphinx-replication/